# trying to put "$gt" into a find. { [CastError: Cast to date failed for value "[object Object]" at path "createdAt "]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this piece of code : `Reviews.find({createdAt : {"$lt" : app.locals.lastDate}})` I wanted to change the `$lt` to `$gt` dynamically.

```
app.post("/scroll", function(req, res){
    console.log("req.body...", req.body);
    var sortCreate = req.body.older == true ? "createdAt" : "-createdAt"
    var greaterOrLess = req.body.older == true ? "$gt" : "$lt";
    greaterOrLess = greaterOrLess.toString()
    console.log("greaterOrLess;;;", greaterOrLess)
    console.log("inside scroll app.locals.lastDate", app.locals.lastDate)
    Reviews.find({createdAt : {"$lt" : app.locals.lastDate}})
    .limit(10)
    .sort(sortCreate).exec()
```

the problem is when I change `Reviews.find({createdAt : {"$lt" : app.locals.lastDate}})`

to

`Reviews.find({createdAt : {greaterOrLess : app.locals.lastDate}})`

I get error:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to date failed for value "[object Object]" at path "createdAt
"]
  message: 'Cast to date failed for value "[object Object]" at path "createdAt"'
,
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'date',
  value: { greaterOrLess: Sun Aug 07 2016 19:25:48 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Ti
me) },
  path: 'createdAt',
  reason: undefined }
```

this part: `console.log("greaterOrLess;;;", greaterOrLess)` prints out `$gt` or `$lt` when I want so why cant I use the `greaterOrLess` variable? it looks like it's a string so I don't know why the variable operator is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have dynamic keys in an object. Instead you can do something like that:

```
var greaterOrLess = req.body.older == true ? {"$gt" : app.locals.lastDate} : {"$lt" : app.locals.lastDate};
Reviews.find({createdAt : greaterOrLess})
```